# Email Signature Image showing file name instead of image

Tags: html, css, image, email

I understand that images in a HTML email signature can be a struggle with different email hosts but I am having an issue (in certain cases) where the images are being replaced by the file name such as  .

I can't even show you this error though as I look at my phone, what was showing a filename last night is now back as an image!

Here is how it should look

[image: Email Signature]

The code is below. If anyone has any clue on why it sometimes doesn't show the images, I would be great for your input

**Code**

```
<html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <meta name="description" content="">
      </head>
      <body style="background:#eee;padding:0;margin:0;">

        <div style="width:600px;background:#fff;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
          <div style="padding:15px 0px;background:#0c6eb7;color:#fff;">
            <div style="padding:5px 15px;">
              <h2 style="margin:0;font-size:18px;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:black; color:#ffffff;">Health Your Way</h2>
              <h3 style="margin:0;margin-bottom:3px;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;">&nbsp;</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style="padding:15px 15px;">
              <p style="margin-top:0px;"></p>
              <h4 style="margin:0;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;color:#0c6eb7;">
                  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vyyo3Cs.png" alt ="Email: " style="height:20px;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:5px;"> <a href="mailto:admin@healthyourway.co.uk" style="color:#0c6eb7;text-decoration:none;">admin@healthyourway.co.uk</a>
                  <b style="display:inline-block;margin:0px 10px;font-weight:normal;">|</b>
                  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Uwbw49m.png" alt="Call: " style="height:20px;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:5px;"> <a href="tel:08006446414" style="color:#0c6eb7;text-decoration:none;">0800 644 6414</a>
                  <b style="display:inline-block;margin:0px 10px;font-weight:normal;">|</b>
                  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/jpcSK1r.png" alt="Website: " style="height:20px;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:5px;"> <a href="http://www.healthyourway.co.uk" style="color:#0c6eb7;text-decoration:none;">healthyourway.co.uk</a>
              </h4>
              <h4 style="margin:0;margin-top:10px;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;color:#0c6eb7;">
                  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bBNmf7g.png" alt="Address" style="height:20px;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:5px;"> <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;width:calc(100% - 30px);color:#0c6eb7;">Queens Gardens Business Centre, 31 Ironmarket, Newcastle-under-Lyme<br>Staffordshire, ST5 1RP</div>
              </h4>
          </div>
          <div style="width:100%;background:#fff;border-top:1px solid #eee;">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:15px;color:#cccccc;font-size:11px;">

             <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="160"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZSms6VI.jpg" width="150" height="60" style="width:150px;height:60px;" alt="Health Your Way"></td>
      <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/sXHE0gU.jpg" width="150" height="60" style="width:150px;height:60px;" alt="CredAbility"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



              </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:15px;color:#cccccc;font-size:11px;"><p>This message may contain confidential information. If you are not the intended recipient please inform the sender that you have received the message in error before deleting it.
    Please do not disclose, copy or distribute information in this e-mail or take any action in reliance on its contents: to do so is strictly prohibited and may be unlawful.</p></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div>

          </div>
      </div>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free image hosting is not recommended for email marketing. Free image hosting at times restrict the number of visits to an image. You image might not load as the users (or yourself) have viewed the image a lot of times in the allocated time frame. My suggestion will be to load it to the server of healthyourway.co.uk and then link it to that.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I searched on internet and decide that maybe you should add image links with `https` instead of `http` to show images.

Comment: Can you share using JsFiddle? I'm using mobile